# ADD thousands separators to an Aggregate Sum SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2019

I am trying to add thousands seperators in an SQL request.
I want to add it on a SUM function, so that the resulting column shows the dati with the thousands separator
from 400000.00 to 400,000.00

That is the line I am trying to fix.
ROUND(SUM(soh.SubTotal),2) as 'Ventes en 2013' --> this means "Sales in 2013"

Thank you !

Comment: Which database platform are you using?  Also, if you have a ui / reporting / presentation layer you should consider doing this type of formatting work there instead of in the database.

Comment: Hey ! I am using the database AdventureWorks2019 if this is what you're asking. Also, I don't think I have the ui/reporting presentation layer you're mentionning.

Comment: Ok, if you're using AdventureWorks2019 then you're most likely using SQL Server 2019.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that's the one

Comment: @squillman Yes it worked ! Thank you so much !